# WebBrowser Win Form

Tags: windows-forms

Buenos días, ¿alguien sabe si es posible renderizar el resultado de una consulta con la clase `WebClient` en un `WebBrowser` de [windows-form](/questions/tagged/windows-form)?

**EDIT**

La respuesta de [@Leandro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3296/2027), me sirvió para lo que necesitaba, lo único es que el codigo tiene un js que esta llamando a recursos que no los cargo con el webclient, no se si existe alguna manera de resolver esto. Estoy obteniendo el resultado de un reporte en reporting services

Comment: a que llamas " renderizar el resultado de una consulta" ? con el webbrowser puedes deplegar una pagina web, ya sea que la consultes a un sitio o cargues un html local. Pero para esto deberias hacer que los datos de la consulta sea convertido en html

Comment: Tengo el html obtenido de un webclient, ahora como lo muestro dentro de un webbrowser, eso es posible?

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió para lo que necesitaba, lo único es que el codigo tiene un js que esta llamando a recursos que no los cargo con el webclient, no se si existe alguna manera de resolver esto. estoy obteniendo el resultado de un reporte en reporting services

Comment: Vuelvo a plantrar la duda, si se trata de reporting service, porque no usas el control ReportViewer para ver el reporte, o quizas exportar el reporte a pdf y visualizar este en el cliente

Answer (score 2):

Si tiene el html como texto en una variable podrias asignarla al `WebBrowser` usando

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

[WebBrowser.DocumentText Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext(v=vs.110).aspx)